# How to modify Y-axis ticks in plotly to accomodate graphs with variying range?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have made a simple bar plot, as shown below

[image]

In X-axis 'Check' ,  'iceCream' and 'OOB' are almost invisible. Is there a way where I can play around with y axis ticks to make them visible without disturbing the sales value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use case for a [logarithmic y-axis](https://plotly.com/python/log-plot/):

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_type="log")
```